# Centos 8 not getting proper list of DNS servers from DHCP

Tags: centos, dhcp

I have a strange thing here.
DHCP server is configured to announce two DNS servers:

```
subnet 192.168.124.0 netmask 255.255.252.0 {
...
  option domain-name-servers 127.0.0.1, 10.0.0.53;
...
}
```

DHCP server offers a proper DNS servers list, tcpdump shows:

```
...
   Domain-Name-Server Option 6, length 8: 127.0.0.1,10.0.0.53
...
```

I have two kinds of DHCP clients: VMs with Centos 7 and Centos 8.
Images are nearly vanilla, just with ssh keys added.

Centos7 VMs are works as expected, /etc/resolv.conf looks correct:

```
❯ cat /etc/resolv.conf
# Generated by NetworkManager
search local
nameserver 127.0.0.1
nameserver 10.0.0.53
```

But on Centos8 it does not!

```
❯ cat /etc/resolv.conf
# Generated by NetworkManager
search local
nameserver 10.0.0.53
```

Note 127.0.0.1 vanished.

I checked network interface configuration and it has no restrictions on that:

```
cat /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-ens160
# Generated by parse-kickstart
TYPE="Ethernet"
DEVICE="ens160"
UUID="6a050c51-e49e-4bb1-9e21-2346bd928dc7"
ONBOOT="yes"
BOOTPROTO="dhcp"
IPV6INIT="no"
```

Also I checked NetworkManager configration, and not found any clues.

What should I check further?
My ideas are exhausted. :(

Comment: Any extra files in `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts`? Does `ifcfg-ens160` correspond to your actual network interface? Anything in `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections` ?

Comment: Show the output of `nmcli connection show --active`

Comment: ens160 is the only interface, and no additional config present.
https://pastebin.com/61jS7CL9

Comment: So, it looks like NetworkManager issue.

When I switched NetworkManager to dhclient instead of its internal dhcp plugin, it works as expected.
`echo -e "[main]\ndhcp=dhclient" > "/etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/dhcp-client.conf"` did the trick.

Comment: Probably warrants a bug report.